# Javascript - Parse file create and save... but not to an object within a class... where does it go?

Tags: javascript, file, parse-platform

Question about saving files to parse... if you save them but then don't add that file to an object within one of your classes... where does it go? Does it expire after a certain amount of time? Or does it sit in some unknown location using up the free space on your Parse account?

Code explaining what I mean:

```
var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  var name = "photo.jpg";

  var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
}

parseFile.save().then(function() {
  // The file has been saved to Parse.

    // WHAT IF I DIDN'T EXECUTE THESE FOUR LINES TO PUT THE SAVED FILED INTO AN OBJECT?
    var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("JobApplication");
    jobApplication.set("applicantName", "Joe Smith");
    jobApplication.set("applicantResumeFile", parseFile);
    jobApplication.save();


}, function(error) {
  // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
});
```

Thanks very much everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is created I believe in a hidden section of your web hosting.

Once it is created it stays around forever unless you do a cleanup. When you perform a cleanup it removes all files that are not referenced by a record in the database.

You can find the cleanup option under Settings -> General, scroll down near the end there's a Clean Up Files section with a Clean Up Files button.

Comment: How do I have access to the ParseFile, if I didn't save it with a ParseObject?